# Have a UITableViewCell show the delete button without the red minus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement a `UITableView` that when I press a button in my `ViewController`, I can see the delete button on the right of the cell, but not the red minus circle on the the left of the cell.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an approach:

1. Have a delete button on a view and assign a method to it
2. In this method, toggle a BOOL `isDeleteEnabled` (or whatever you name it) to `TRUE`
3. Reload the `UITableView` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for that BOOL value
4. If `TRUE` then load the all the `UITableViewCell` as custom cells
   with delete button on it (You need to set the selector method for
   deletion of a row)
5. Delete as many cells as you want by tapping that button on the cells
6. After deleting your choices you can again press the main button and
   toggle the value for `isDeleteEnabled`
7. Again reload `UITableView` and this time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
   check the value of `isDeleteEnabled` - which will be `FALSE`. So, you need to load normal(or your original) UITableViewCells.

I have done the very similar thing following this approach.

Also, I haven't posted the code for it for three reasons:

- *It would be too lengthy in size*
- *The code his available at my work machine (to which I am not having
  access right now)*
- *It will ruin the joy of coding such a task. Do it yourself. You will
  enjot it.*

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I decided to implement it manually the way you suggested and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

that simple if you dont want the minus sign to appear, consider implementing you own solution than default one, insert a delete button and provide an animation to it, do as you require

Answer (score -2):

You dont need a button action to trigger this. If you implement the following delegate you can directly swipe and delete the cell.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
   //Delete the row
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to swipe. I need to press a button and then the delete button should appear. But I do not want the left red minus circle to appear. Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to write your own method in that case.

Answer (score -2):

My idea, don't use button but u can swipe the cell to delete with the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
         //Use actionsheet or deleteRowsAtIndexPaths
    }

 }
```

Comment: he want the delete button but not the minus sign

Comment: Yes, I suggest him to swipe the cell to see delete button. If he want to get like his wish just custom code.

Answer (score -3):

Override to support editing the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }    
}
```